# How to sign correctly a Powershell script for AllSigned ExecutionPolicy?

Tags: powershell, code-signing

We have an application where we use several PowerShell scripts. We received a complain regarding about they aren't signed and unable to run them if they have the strictest Execution Policy - AllSigned.

I signed with our certificate issued by well-known issuer via signtool as we do it for dlls and exe app but even after that there is an issue if I try running the script I'm getting warning:

Do you want to run software from this untrusted publisher?

It's signed by a certificate issued by know CA (Sectigo). Only how can I get rid of this warning is to add the certificate to Trusted Publishers. It's not good for customers to do those steps (but maybe it's necessary security step). Note: With the same certificate, we sign exe app and it works fine and Windows doesn't complain. (Look like PowerShell policies are stricter.)

**Is it possible somehow avoid getting this warning on a customer side without manually adding our certificate into Trusted Publishers? Looks to me that it is not possible.**

What I've found out so far:

I've searched across internet and it looks like there is no solution for that. Even if I used  [PowerShell script signed by Microsoft Corporation](https://microsoft.github.io/CSS-Exchange/Security/EOMTv2/) I get the same warning unless I add to the Trusted Publishers folder.

Also e.g. [HP](https://developers.hp.com/hp-client-management/doc/powershell-execution-policies) directly recommends to add the certificate manually to the cert store.

In a [documenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.3) about execution policies is written in AllSigned section: **Prompts you before running scripts from publishers that you haven't yet classified as trusted or untrusted.**

From those all information, I got it as there is no way how to avoid getting this warning on a customer side without adding to the cert store. I want just to assure myself I'm right.

Comment: See: [Hey, Scripting Guy! How Can I Sign Windows PowerShell Scripts with an Enterprise Windows](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-sign-windows-powershell-scripts-with-an-enterprise-windows-pki-part-1-of-2/)

Comment: Yes, I already checked this but also from this it looks to me a customer have to add our certificate manually into Trusted Publishers. I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to do it without this step. We run a powershell script during app install and if the customer has AllSigned policy it failed until it adds to cert store.

Comment: Maybe you can run the script with powershell -executionpolicy bypass.  The policy is only to keep people from *unknowingly* running powershell scripts.

Comment: @js2010, unfortunately, this doesn't help. bypass policy is ignored, if AllSigned is set via group policy.